# How to deal with order of operation with the inputs from the user in Java?

Tags: java, oop, operator-precedence

I am currently working on an assignment where I will ask for the user's input of fractions and the operations between these fractions, the user will enter "quit" in order for the program to stop prompting information. The program should solve problems like: 1/2 + 1/4 * 1/6 - 2/7.

**Here is how the input looks like:**

```
Enter numerator: 1
Enter denominator: 2
Enter operation: +

Enter numerator: 1
Enter denominator: 4
Enter operation: *

Enter numerator: 1
Enter denominator: 6
Enter operation: -

Enter numerator: 2
Enter denominator: 7
Enter operation: quit
```

**Here is my approach:**

To take care of this BEDMAS problem I use 5 objects and it should work.
(In the following example the 5 objects are 1, 2, 3, +, x)

1 + 2 x 3 + 4 x 5

Look at first 3 fractions.
If any operator is x or /
then perform that operation.

1 + 6 + 4 x 5

Look at first 3  fractions .
Since none of them are x or /
then operate on the first 2.

7 + 4 x 5

Look at first 3  fractions  .
if any operator is x or /
then perform that operation.

7 + 20

If less than 3, solve!

27

The result supposes to be: 43/168
However, after I run the program,it gives me 26/48

Can somebody tell me from where did I got messed up in the program?
Thank you in advance!

**Here is my what is happening in the main class:**

```java
public class app {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        Fraction f1 = null;
        Fraction f2 = null;
        Fraction f3 = null;
        Fraction result = null;
        boolean stop = false;
        String op1 = "", op2 = "";
        while (!stop) {
            System.out.println("input fraction: ");
            Fraction f = Fraction.inputNewFraction();
            result = f;
            if (f1 == null) {
                f1 = f;
            } else {
                if (f2 == null) {
                    f2 = f;
                } else {
                    f3 = f;
                }
            }
            scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print("input operation:");
            String s = scan.nextLine();
            // System.out.print(s.equals("+"));
            if (s.equals("+") || s.equals("-") || s.equals("*") || s.equals("/")) {
                if (f2 == null) {
                    op1 = s;
                } else {
                    if (f3 == null) {
                        op2 = s;
                    } else if (f3 != null) {
                        if (op1 == "+" || op1 == "-") {       // check: CORRECT
                            f1 = f1.opCal(f2, op1);
                            f2 = f3;
                            op1 = op2;

                        } else {
                            f2 = f2.opCal(f3, op2);                            
                        }
                        
                        f3 = null;
                        op2 = s;

                    }
                }
            } else {
                stop = true;

            }
            System.out.println("f1: " + f1.toString());
            if (f2 != null)
                System.out.println("f2: " + f2.toString());
            if (f3 != null)
                System.out.println("f3: " + f3.toString());
                System.out.println("result: " + result.toString());
            if (f2 != null) {
                result = f1.opCal(f2, op1);
                System.out.println("result: " + result.toString());
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

**Here is what is happening in the Fraction class:**

```java
class Fraction {
  
  private int numerator;
  private int denominator;

  public Fraction(int myNumerator, int myDenominator) {   // constructor Fraction now holds numerator, 
    numerator = myNumerator;                              // and denominator at the same time
    denominator = myDenominator;
  }

  public Fraction opCal(Fraction fraction, String promptOperation) {
    int newNumerator;
    int newDenominator;

    switch (promptOperation) {
      case "+":
        newNumerator = (numerator * fraction.denominator) + (fraction.numerator * denominator);
        newDenominator = denominator * fraction.denominator;
        return new Fraction(newNumerator, newDenominator);
      case "-":
        newNumerator = (numerator * fraction.denominator) - (fraction.numerator * denominator);
        newDenominator = denominator * fraction.denominator;
        return new Fraction(newNumerator, newDenominator);
      case "*":
        newNumerator = numerator * fraction.numerator;
        newDenominator = denominator * fraction.denominator;
        return new Fraction(newNumerator, newDenominator);
      case "/":
        newNumerator = numerator * fraction.denominator;
        newDenominator = denominator * fraction.numerator;
        return new Fraction(newNumerator, newDenominator);
      default:
        System.out.println("Invalid operator");
        return new Fraction(0, 0); // Return a default Fraction object
    }
  }

  public static Fraction inputNewFraction() throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter numerator:");
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter denominator:");
        int b = scan.nextInt();
        return new Fraction(a, b);
    }
 
  public String toString() {
    return numerator +  " / " + denominator;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to give you two hints: 1. please use a debugger to get a deeper understanding of what is happening in your code(in the end I guess what goes horribly wrong, besides other things that go minorly wrong is, that you overwrite the result on every loop? 2. rethink on your program structure! the given code is sort of ugly in it's workflow. Maybe you can shove all inputs in a list first before you resume calculating.

Comment: Another hint: you may want to learn about programming language parsing. Parsers for arithmetic expressions have been studied for decades.

Comment: In my opinion, it is most often better to simply allow the User to enter (or paste) an entire math equation to have evaluated and then, be provided with a mathematical result.  Of course parsing would definitely be required but, I think it's worth it. Here is where you can get runnable code for a [Fractional Math Demo](https://controlc.com/15fa5183).